# Can Gradle generate a POM in such a way that it doesn't unnecessarily touch the output file?

Tags: gradle, pom.xml

We're creating a POM file like so:

```
task createPom {
   doLast {
      pom {
         project {
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.ext.pomVersion
         }
      }.writeTo("${buildDir}/pom.xml")
   }
}
```

This `writeTo` eagerly writes to the file even if no changes have occurred, which causes the jar to change, so later expensive tasks in the build (indexing, signing, building installers) all have to run as well.

I thought about writing to a temp file and diffing the two files somehow, but it seems like I'd have to write a lot of boilerplate just to do that, so I'm wondering whether there is a proper way to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to configure task's [inputs and outputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) which are used to determine whether your task is up-to-date or not. Here, how it should be done:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

ext {
  pomVersion = '3.1.4.5'
}

group = 'lolgroup'

task createPom {
  outputs.file "${buildDir}/pom.xml"
  inputs.property('group', project.group)
  inputs.property('name', project.name)
  inputs.property('pomVersion', project.ext.pomVersion)

  doLast {
    pom {
      project {
        groupId inputs.properties['group']
        artifactId inputs.properties['name']
        version inputs.properties['pomVersion']
      }
    }.writeTo("${buildDir}/pom.xml")
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/45024154) you can find a demo.

Comment: Aha, so there is a way to have arbitrary inputs. I assume I also have to put something in to make it know it has to remake the pom if the dependencies change too, and that I can use a property for that as well.

Comment: OK, the missing one appears to be:     inputs.property('generatedDependencies', model.generatedDependencies)